# How to store specific data on certain lines of an empty file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I would like to store some specific data (`var1=23`, `var2=true`, `var3=alpha`, `var4=55`) to following lines of a file using bash script, for example

```
line_1 -> var3, line_2 -> var4, line_3 -> var1, line_4 -> var2.
```

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to questions that get useful responses - especially [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Avoid the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Show what you tried, inputs and outputs, and any error messages. Also read over [this page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) of reasons people will ignore you, especially "No Attempt", "No Code", and "No MCVE".   Be [concise](https://www.google.com/search?q=concise). Where do the values come from? Are you writing code or just loading vars? Are you adding lines or editing them?

Comment: @PaulHodges i have an empty file where i have to store the data from above mentioned four variables. That data should not be stored in order rather e.g. value of "var3" should be stored on first line of the file.

Comment: "Show what you tried, inputs and outputs, and any error messages." Please edit your original post.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
printf '%s\n' "$var3" "$var4" "$var1" "$var2" > output.file
```

The printf command will re-use the format string until all the given data is used up.

If that is not sufficient, then please update your question to provide more clear requirements.